# Filling a column with Case When Statement in reference to another column

Tags: ms-access

I am fairly new to SQL language and I am trying to do some work for Uni in Access. I have three columns: Bindugen, with values shown below, and then blank Columns Code and 33/SDGL:

Bindungen: 33,811, / 811,SDGL,33,/ 33,812,SDGL, / 812,SDGL,/ 811, (etc.)

My main column is Bindungen and I want to fill the others in relation to that one. Basically in the column 33/SDGL I tried to do the Update Case When Statement shown below. It obviously didn't work.

```
SELECT 
FROM Codes;
UPDATE (Codes)
SET 33/SDGL ( CASE 
       WHEN Bindungen = "*," THEN Allein
       WHEN Bindungen = "33,*," Or "*,33," THEN 33
       WHEN Bindungen = "SDGL,*," Or "*,SDGL," THEN SDGL
       ELSE Both
    END);
```

My goal for the 33/SDGL column is that when Bindungen is: "*," = Allein / "*,33," Or "33,*," = 33 / "*,SDGL," Or "SDGL,*," = SDGL

and for the rest = BOTH

Could someone help me write this SQL code?

Also for the Code column, I would like it to find from Bindungen which code is there (eg: 811 or 812). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not use the CASE statement. You need to write a SWITCH statement instead, like this:

```
SWITCH(Bindungen = "*,", Allein, Bindungen = "33,*,", 33, Bindungen = "*,33,", 33, 
             Bindungen = "SDGL,*,", SDGL, Bindungen = "*,SDGL,", SDGL, BOTH)
```

Also note that in this situation, `Allein`, `SDGL`, and `BOTH` must ALL be fields that you are selecting from. If you just want the text instead of a field value, wrap those words in "double quotes".